# How do I correctly hide model relationships from returning in toArray() or toJson()?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a project where I'm writing an API, and with a lot of the models, I'm trying to hide their parent relationships from being returned, like so

```
<?php namespace Viper\Model;

class User_Token extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users_tokens';

    protected $fillable = array(
        'user_id', 'token'
    );

    protected $hidden = array(
        'id', 'user_id', 'user'
    );

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

In the Laravel documentation, for the [Eloquent > Converting to Array or Json](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json) section, it clearly says

> Note: When hiding relationships, use the relationship's method name,
>   not the dynamic accessor name.

What exactly does this mean? In the above example, both the method name and the dynamic accessor name are the same, and I can't for the life of me, think of a situation where this wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
protected $hidden = array(
        'id', 'user_id', 'user'
                           ^^^ relationship's method name which is "user"
);
```

if you want to hide the relationship , you have to include `method name` under hidden attributes. From your hidden attributes, i can see, you are perfectly hiding `user` relationship from Array and JSON conversion . However, if you have 'user' column in your `users_tokens` table, I have no idea what Laravel will behave.

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Comment: All of my method and column names are specifically chosen so that they don't conflict. I just don't understand the difference between the method name and the dynamic accessor name, since the accessor name is derived from the method name...

Comment: Thanks, this work perfect for me. so if I have userPhone() relationship, laravel will put user_phone to json. so I had to put 'userPhone' in $hidden array NOT the user_phone. hope this will help to someone.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same question and decided to clarify this with PR to Laravel docs.
Seems like there is no difference and that note was incorrect.

https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/3351