# How to remove spatie/laravel-permissions related data on querying

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-6, laravel-permission

I use [spatie/laravel-permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) package in my project and try remove `roles` relation data when querying:

```
$jobs = Job::with(['user' => function($user) {
     $user->without('roles', 'companies')->select('id', 'name');
}])->get();
```

But when I run this query `roles` relation data is not removed. How I can remove it from query response data?

Comment: What do you do with the `$jobs` after you query them and how do you know that the `roles` relation is there?

Comment: I seen roles relation data on response to my vue js application

Comment: Here is [response example](http://snippi.com/s/6ti6vzb)

Comment: This might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671191/how-do-i-correctly-hide-model-relationships-from-returning-in-toarray-or-tojso